# New to JMESPath -> filter array without key/value pairs

Tags: jmespath

I am trying to filter a list of objects with jmes,

so far, I am able to filter a quite big datasructure, so I get a list of a structure like this:

```
[{
    id: "foo"
    name: "bar"
    targets: ["something", "somethingelse", "blabla"]
}, ...]
```

what I need, is to filter this list so I only get the elements that contain "blabla" in the targets array. I don´t seem to find such a thing. What is the proper way of implementing such a filter? All the infos I find are for filtering an array that contains key/value pairs...

Answer (score 4):

I think you want:

```
[?contains(targets, 'blabla')]
```

See http://jmespath.org/specification.html#built-in-functions for all available functions.